# Adding Objects to a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, object, binary-search-tree

I have an insert method but it only seems to work with integers.  I've been trying to change it so it works with objects but I can't figure it out.

Insert method in node class.

```
    //Method: insert node into tree
public void insert(E insertValue){
    if((Integer)insertValue < (Integer)this.data){
        //add this node to the left of the current node
        if(this.leftNode ==null)
            this.leftNode = new Node<E>(insertValue);
        else
            this.leftNode.insert(insertValue);
    }

    else if ((Integer) insertValue > (Integer) this.data)
        if(this.rightNode == null)
            this.rightNode = new Node<E>(insertValue);

    else
        this.rightNode.insert(insertValue);


}
```

Insert method in BST class

```
 public void insertNode(E insertValue) {
    if (this.root == null)
        this.root = new Node<E> (insertValue);
    else 
        this.root.insert(insertValue);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well you are casting everything to an integer. If you want to compare objects use insertValue.CompareTo(this.data) and use the result of that. Note the objects must implement comparable (which has to be the case anyways for bst's)

Comment: All that happens is a syntax error.  I already tried casting them as strings but it didn't work.  What am I missing?

Comment: `(Integer)insertValue < (Integer)this.data` needs to be `insertValue.compareTo(this.data) < 0` and the same applies to the > check just with >. This assumes this.data is of type E (this needs to be true)